# How can I remove lines matching foo but not matching bar?

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

Assume I want to remove the 2nd and 3rd, but not the 4th line in the following file (those which match foo but do not match bar), can I easily do this with e.g. sed?

```
text
foo some more text
even more foo text
some foo text with bar
```

Comment: Has to be with sed?

Comment: No, other "quick and dirty" tools are fine as well, it was just that sed looked like the most straightforward at first.  Actually Stéphane's answer showed that lots of other tools works just as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several alternatives:

```
awk '! (/foo/ && !/bar/)'
awk '/bar/ || !/foo/'
sed -e /bar/b -e /foo/d
sed '/foo/{/bar/!d;}'
perl -ne 'print unless /foo/ && !/bar/'
```

GNU `grep` with PCRE support:

```
grep -vP '^(?!.*bar).*foo'
```

(using PCRE's *negative look-ahead operator* `(?!...)`).

Of those, only `perl` allows in-place editing portably (on systems where any version of `perl` is installed) with the `-i` option.

Standard `sed` doesn't do in-place editing. However the `sed` of some recent BSDs allow it with the `-i ''` option and GNU `sed` with `-i` (both modelled after `perl`) as an extension.

Very recent versions of GNU `awk` also allow it with `-i inplace`.

Comment: Creating an alias for yourself?

Comment: @G-Man, see http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/3230

Comment: I see. Funny how they have the resources to change the UI, but not to make the changes that users ask for. Sigh.

Comment: Accepting this one, because I like the diversity of answers.  I will probably use one of the `sed` answers in practice, because `sed` allows in-place modifiaction of files, which is what I need (but did not specify in the question).

Answer (score 5):

It seems to work for me this way:

```sh
sed '/foo/{/bar/!d;}' my_file
```

Comment: If the lines would have different content this would not necessarily delete the second and third line and leave the fourth alone as specified as a requirement in the question.

Comment: @Anthon, the requirement is in the question's subject. _How can I remove lines matching foo but not matching bar?_. And this answer addresses it.